# xxforms:tree view of xforms:select1 control

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to display items retrieved from an XML DB using xforms:select1 control using appearance=xxforms:tree.  The items appear collapsed or expanded automatically and the behaviour is not the same for all the items retrieved.  I have the following questions regarding xxforms:tree view:

- how to make sure this view shows sub-nodes (those expandable/collapsable using +/- icon) as collapsed or expanded always, irrespective of, for example, the no. of nodes covered by the + icon?
- how to render select1 with tree appearance without making any of the items hyperlinks?
- how to make sure no item is highlighted/selected by default?

...and although the docs say xxforms:menu is also a possible appearance (URL http://www.orbeon.com/orbeon/doc/reference-xforms-extensions#tree), the details are not available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About which branches of the tree should be open** — By default all the nodes leading to selected nodes are open, this so the selected values are all visible. But you can change this default behavior and specify which nodes should be open using the `xxforms:open` attribute. For more on this, see the section "Controlling which tree nodes are initially open" on [Selection Controls](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/selection-controls). Note that this feature was added in October 2010, so it is not included in Orbeon Forms 3.8, and until Orbeon Forms 3.9 is released, you'll need to get a nightly build for this.

**About using links in the tree** — At this point, the nodes you can click on in the `select1 appearance="xxforms:tree` control are rendered as links, so users know that this is something they can click on to make a selection. I assume that you don't want them to show as links because the tree might be "read-only" in your case (for information only, not to make a selection). This isn' supported at this point. As a workaround, you could use CSS to change the pointer and appearance of links in the tree so to users they don't even notice that this those are links.

**About the menu appearance** — It works very much like the tree appearance. See for instance this [example using the menu](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/xforms-sandbox/samples/menu.xhtml).

Comment: It is weird that a node automatically gets selected in the select1 control, xxforms:tree appearance, shown in a dialog control and sometimes the path to that node does not involve other nodes which are all shown open (and sometimes a mix of nodes, open and closed while the selected node is outside the path of those nodes): how to disable automatic selection of an arbitrary node shown via the xxforms:tree in a dialog control (most of the times, this node which is selected has empty textual content)?

Comment: I think that what you are experimenting is that when you click on the "+" or "-" in the tree, the corresponding item gets selected. In fact you'd like an item to be selected only when you click explicitly on its label. This behavior was changed after the 3.8 release. If you're using Orbeon Forms 3.8, I would recommend you get a nightly build, and see if it works better for you.

Comment: No, I am not experimenting with clicking + or - and checking what gets selected.  I do not click anywhere.  When the dialog is shown, it renders the select1 control with all nodes beyond the first node with empty content rendered as open, with that first node with empty content selected: I am doing this for each item - <xforms:label ref="fn:concat(fn:node-name(.),': ',fn:string(.))"/><xforms:value ref="."/>  When current node (.) is empty, the node gets selected and all nodes after this (below this in rendered select1 control) are open.  When I set value to non-empty, renders okay.

Comment: If this is another issue, we'll need a way to reproduce it. Could you edit your question and paste in stand-alone example that we can use as a test case to reproduce the issue, along with instructions on how to reproduce it?